# Highcharts: Custom button - symbol is misplaced

Tags: image, button, highcharts

I have added a new custom button, with my own symbol image:
But the image is not placed as should :(
Can some one help?
Thanks
Chanan

[image]

Here is how i added the button:

```
    exporting: {
        buttons: {
            'myButton': {
                _id: 'myButton',
                symbol: 'url(images/gallery/reset_zoom.jpg)',
                x: -62,
                symbolFill: '#B5C9DF',
                hoverSymbolFill: '#779ABF',
                onclick: function() {
                    alert('click!')
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the answer :) using symbolX and symbolY

```
    exporting: {
        buttons: {
            'myButton': {
                _id: 'myButton',
                symbol: 'url(images/gallery/reset_zoom.jpg)',
                symbolX:6,
                symbolY:6,
                x: -62,
                symbolFill: '#B5C9DF',
                hoverSymbolFill: '#779ABF',
                onclick: function() {
                    alert('click!')
                }
            }
        }
    }
```